# Get last inserted record's Primary Key in "declarative_base()"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wanna to get **Primary Key** of last inserted, I already know two way for this :

1) "lastrowid" with "raw SQL"

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, text

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

meta = MetaData()

tbl = Table('tbl', meta,
    Column('f1', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('f2', String(64))
)

tbl.create(engine)

sql = text("INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (NULL, 'some_data')")
res = engine.execute(sql)

print(res.lastrowid)
```

2) "inserted_primary_key" with "insert()"

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

meta = MetaData()

tbl = Table('tbl', meta,
    Column('f1', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('f2', String(64))
)

tbl.create(engine)

ins = tbl.insert().values(f2='some_data')
res = engine.execute(ins)

print(res.inserted_primary_key)
```

but my problem is **"declarative_base()"**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class TBL(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl'

    f1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    f2 = Column(String(64))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

rcd = TBL(f2='some_data')

session.add(rcd)
session.commit()
```

If i do this:

```
res = session.add(rcd)
```

It give me "None". or if i do this:

```
res = session.commit()
```

same thing happend. My question is:

Is there any good way to access "lastrowid" or "inserted_primary_key" in case of "declarative_base()"?

What is the best approach ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After calling `session.commit()`, accessing `rcd.f1` will return its generated primary key. SQLAlchemy automatically reloads the object from database after it has been [expired by the commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit).